# Using set function recursively in the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id     events 
1        [a]
1        [a,b,c,d]
2        [d,e]
2        [d,e,f]
```

I want to eliminate the common items in the subsequent rows.. resulting in:

```
id     events 
1        [a]
1        [b,c,d] 
2        [d,e]
2        [f]
```

I know set function does it at a column level but is it possible to do this recursively on a row with apply or lambda functions?

Comment: I don't understand the indexing, why not 1 2 3 4 ? And should not it be [a] [b] [c d] [e f] as a result ?

Comment: `This doesnt work if I have multiple Ids and each Id has its own unique set ..` And how is that reflected in the question???

Comment: apologies mate.. i edited the question now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), remove duplicates by both columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then aggregate back:

```
df = (df.explode('events')
        .drop_duplicates(['id','events'])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg({'id':'first', 'events':list}))
print (df)
   id     events
0   1        [a]
1   1  [b, c, d]
2   2     [d, e]
3   2        [f]
```

Comment: Hi @jerael: I am using pandas-1.1.2, which is the latest version, i dont think explode is  available in it?

Comment: @thealchemist - Sure, for 100%

Comment: thanks.. when i try : print(pd.__version__) i get 0.24.2 and i am still getting the error..

Comment: @thealchemist - yes, because `0.24.0` is oldier like `pandas 1.1.1`

Comment: thanks for your help.. i am sure your solution works.. i just need to figure out the dependencies..

Comment: @thealchemist - yes, need pandas `version 0.25.0+` for `explode`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using apply and using a global list

```
list_ = []
def filterList (X):
result = []
for x in X:
if not x in list_:
list_.append (x)
result.append (x)
return result 

df ['event'].apply (lambda x: filterList(x))
```